# Updating SQL db with List - Java and MyBatis

Tags: java, sql, performance, oop, mybatis

Is it possible to insert a list in MyBatis?

This is the Java code:

```
@Override
    public void createSubjectPrivileges(final List<SubjectPrivilegesFormDTO> subjectPrivilegesFormDTOList) {
        this.auditingSqlSession.update("createSubjectPrivileges",3,subjectPrivilegesFormDTOList);
    }
```

What would be the MyBatis code, in case this is possible?

```
<insert id="createSubjectPrivileges" parameterType="?">
        insert into x (
        a,
        b,
        c
        ) values (
        #{d, jdbcType=NUMERIC},
        #{e, jdbcType=NUMERIC},
        #{f, jdbcType=NUMERIC}
        )
    </insert>
```

I can always iterate throught the list in Java and insert one each time, but that's not very good in performance terms, from my point of view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql generation [facilities](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach) in mybatis to generate statement that will insert a list but this is not a good way to do that.

Doing loop in java and using [BatchExecutor](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/executor/BatchExecutor.html) is a [recommended](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/mybatis-user/oracle$20batch$20update/mybatis-user/8QxLH7XuYlU/mLT5WT_TokoJ) way to do batch operations. Batch executor uses JDBC batching which eliminates multiple roundtrips to database. Another benefit is that prepared statements are used and this makes statements faster if compared with large generated statement that has multiple inserts in it.